# SQL Server - Select and insert rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to select data from table `nombre` and insert it into table `numbers` row by row.

This is my query but it doesn't works:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT [number1], [number2], [number3] FROM [dbo].[nombre])
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[numbers] ([new1], [new2], [new3])
    VALUES([number1], [number2], [number3])
END
```

Comment: What do you mean, "row by row"?

Comment: See James McDonnell's answer. As a general bit of advice, SQL is much better suited for set-based operations than it is for iterative code like you're trying to write. Why add a row at a time when you can add them all at once? I'd suggest that you avoid writing SQL that operates on one row at a time unless you're sure that there's no other way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert rows from a select statement.

```
insert into TableA(Column1, Column2)
select Column1FromTableB, Column2FromTableB from TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the data from nombre to numbers
create the numbers table with same columns the proceed with query.

insert into numbers (new1, new2, new3)
select number1, number2, number3 from nombre

### Result:Table-nombre

number1 number2 number3
  1        2       3
Result:Table-numbers
new1    new2    new3
 1       2        3